# Unit testing in AngularJS - Mocking Services and Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

In Angular everything seems to have a steep learning curve and unit testing an Angular app definitely doesn't escape this paradigm.

When I started with TDD and Angular I felt that I was spending twice (maybe more) as much time figuring out just how to test and maybe even more just getting my tests set up correctly. But as [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm) put it in his blog there are ups and downs in the angular learning process. His graph is definitely my experience with Angular.

However as I have progressed in learning Angular and unit testing as well, now i feel that I am spending much less time setting up tests and much more time making tests go from red to green - which is a good feeling.

So I have come across different methods of setting up my unit test to mock services and promises and I thought I would share what I have learned and also ask the question of:

> Are there any other or better ways of accomplishing this?

So onto the code, that what we all come for here anyways - not to listen to some guy talk about his love, err accomplishments learning a framework.

This is how I started out mocking my services and promises, I'll use a controller, but services and promises can be mocked in other places obviously.

```
describe('Controller: Products', function () {
    var//iable declarations
        $scope,
        $rootScope,
        ProductsMock = {
            getProducts: function () {
            } // There might be other methods as well but I'll stick to one for the sake of consiseness
        },
        PRODUCTS = [{},{},{}]
    ;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('App.Controllers.Products');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_) {
        //Set up our mocked promise
        var promise = { then: jasmine.createSpy() };

        //Set up our scope
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        //Set up our spies
        spyOn(ProductsMock, 'getProducts').andReturn(promise);

        //Initialize the controller
        $controller('ProductsController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            Products: ProductsMock
        });

        //Resolve the promise
        promise.then.mostRecentCall.args[0](PRODUCTS);

    }));

    describe('Some Functionality', function () {
        it('should do some stuff', function () {
            expect('Stuff to happen');
        });
    });
});
```

For us this worked, but as time went on I thought there must be a better way. For one I hated the

```
promise.then.mostRecentCall
```

*thing*, and if we wanted to reinitialise the controller then we had to pull it out of the beforeEach block and inject it individually into each test.

> There has to be a better way...

Now I ask does anyone have other ways to set tests up, or and thoughts or feeling on the way I have chose to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Then I came across another post, blog, stackoverflow example (you pick it I was probably there), and I saw the use of the $q library. Duh! Why set up a whole mock promise when we can just use the tool that Angular gives us. Our code looks nicer and makes more sense to look at - no ugly promise.then.mostRecent *thing*.

Next in the iteration of unit testing was this:

```
describe('Controller: Products', function () {
    var//iable declarations
        $scope,
        $rootScope,
        $q,
        $controller,
        productService,
        PROMISE = {
            resolve: true,
            reject: false
        },
        PRODUCTS = [{},{},{}] //constant for the products that are returned by the service
    ;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('App.Controllers.Products');
        module('App.Services.Products');
    });


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, _products_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        productService = _products_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    function setupController(product, resolve) {
        //Need a function so we can setup different instances of the controller
        var getProducts = $q.defer();

        //Set up our spies
        spyOn(products, 'getProducts').andReturn(getProducts.promise);

        //Initialise the controller
        $controller('ProductsController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            products: productService
        });

        // Use $scope.$apply() to get the promise to resolve on nextTick().
        // Angular only resolves promises following a digest cycle,
        // so we manually fire one off to get the promise to resolve.
        if(resolve) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                getProducts.resolve();
            });
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                getProducts.reject();
            });
        }
    }

    describe('Resolving and Rejecting the Promise', function () {
        it('should return the first PRODUCT when the promise is resolved', function () {
            setupController(PRODUCTS[0], PROMISE.resolve); // Set up our controller to return the first product and resolve the promise. 
            expect('to return the first PRODUCT when the promise is resolved');
        });

        it('should return nothing when the promise is rejected', function () {
            setupController(PRODUCTS[0], PROMISE.reject); // Set up our controller to return first product, but not to resolve the promise. 
            expect('to return nothing when the promise is rejected');
        });
    });
});
```

This started to feel like the way it should be set up. We can mock what we need to mock we can set our promise to resolve and reject so we can truly test the two possible outcomes. This feels good...

Answer (score 3):

The main point in your own answer about using `$q.defer` sounds good. My only additions would be that

```
setupController(0, true)
```

is not particularly clear, due to the parameters `0` and `true`, and then the `if` statement that uses this. Also, passing the mock of `products` into the `$controller` function itself seems unusual, and means you might have 2 different `products` services available. One directly injected into the controller, and one injected by the usual Angular DI system into other services. I think better to use `$provide` to inject mocks and then everywhere in Angular will have the same instance for any test.

Putting this all together, something like the following seems better, which can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/p676TYnAIb9QlD7MPIHu?p=preview

```
describe('Controller: ProductsController', function() {

  var PRODUCTS, productsMock,  $rootScope, $controller, $q;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(module(function($provide){
    PRODUCTS = [{},{},{}]; 
    productsMock = {};        
    $provide.value('products', productsMock);
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, _products_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    products = _products_;
  }));

  var createController = function() {
    return $controller('ProductsController', {
      $scope: $rootScope
    })
  };

  describe('on init', function() {
    var getProductsDeferred;

    var resolve = function(results) {
      getProductsDeferred.resolve(results);
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }

    var reject = function(reason) {
      getProductsDeferred.reject(reason);
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
      getProductsDeferred = $q.defer();
      productsMock.getProducts = function() {
        return getProductsDeferred.promise;
      };
      createController();
    });

    it('should set success to be true if resolved with product', function() {
      resolve(PRODUCTS[0]);
      expect($rootScope.success).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should set success to be false if rejected', function() {
      reject();
      expect($rootScope.success).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Notice that lack of `if` statement, and the limitation of the `getProductsDeferred` object, and `getProducts` mock, to the scope of a `describe` block. Using this sort of pattern, means you can add other tests, on other methods of `products`, without polluting the mock `products` object, or the `setupController` function you have, with all the possible methods / combinations you need for the tests.

As a sidebar, I notice:

```
module('App.Controllers.Products');
module('App.Services.Products');
```

means you are separating your controllers and services into different Angular modules. I know certain blogs have recommended this, but I suspect this overcomplicated things, and a single module per app is ok. If you then refactor, and make services and directives completely separate reusable components, then it would be time to put them into a separate module, and use them as you would any other 3rd party module.

Edit: Corrected `$provide.provide` to `$provide.value`, and fixed some of the ordering of instantiation of controller/services, and added a link to Plunkr

Comment: Thanks Michal for taking the time to have a look. However I think you might have missed the complete picture of implementation. I am not passing in 2 products services. One is a global variable so we can pass it around - products, and the other PRODUCTS is the actual products that are returned from the promise. Finally the 3rd use of the word product is a parameter in the setupController fct, this just determines which product I would like to return and the boolean determines if the promise was reject or resolved - need to test both instances. I will rename some vars and add some more comments

Comment: We need the separate modules as for unit testing this is ideal - if you dont understand why i can go further into detail. But boils down to not needing functionality of other modules in the unit test of unrelated modules. And yes we are making modules separate reusable components.

Comment: I like the implementation of resolve and reject, but what if i need to test the controller with a different setup - with your method I am tied to one controller setup. However with a function setupController i can choose exactly how I would like the controller to be setup and it makes the code much more concise.

Comment: I understand that you're not passing in 2 services, but just wanted to say that it's more usual (from what I know) to use `$provide` to inject mocks of services during tests. I've renamed a variable to be `PRODUCTS[0]` to be more consistent with your names. I realise that my code wouldn't quite have worked as you wanted, and fixed in answer and at bit.ly/OIPZoQ. I now agree you still need a createController function, and I have edited my answer to include one: but the important point it does nothing but create a controller: all definitions of stub methods are separate, and in a describe block

Comment: "However with a function `setupController` i can choose exactly how I would like the controller to be setup". If you allow parameters in the `setupController` function which controls mocks of services, then for every service that the controller might be injected with, and so have to be tested against, this function will have to be changed, with more `if` conditions, and more parameters passed to it to setup the mock services. This feels like a violation of the Open/closed principal (if I understand it correctly), and so should be avoided if there is an alternative.

Comment: I will have a closer look later, but as we are running TDD everything is tested to the fullest before hand.

Comment: One thing I dont like about your implementation of the mocking of the products service - this is not need and extra code. If you look at my controller you see i actually just use the same service and allow if to do its thing, but I intercept the calls with jasmine. I started out doing things your way but it was extra work that never needed to be done.

Comment: About the mock of the service `$provide` vs. `spyOn`: I don't think there's much in it really. I would argue that mine is slightly better, as the bare minimum of the service has been created in order to test the controller. If the controller attempted to use another function of the service, which I hadn't explicitly mocked, then an error would be raised during the test, which I would say is a good thing.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but then you are not able to test the functionality of the controller completely. So the unit test would not actually test the true functionality of the code.

Comment: Also how can you control what the mocked service should return? If you would like it to return something. Thats what the jasmine spies are there for.

Comment: You can combine the approaches of `$provide` and spies. They're not mutually exclusive: you can see more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22954343/1319998 . Regarding your last question: the function is defined in the test and so can return anything you like. But yes, it might be better to use a spy to a) check that it's been called, and b) define the return value closer to the test, which might be clearer. However you should also make sure that you test what happens after the call to the service. In my case, it was checking that `success` was set to true on the scope.