# When should I use $provide versus Jasmine Spies in my Angular JS Unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I work on a large Angular App and initially we done a lot of our tests by using $provide to mock services. However we now have a lot of Jasmine Spies in our tests in order to stub and spy on services.

i.e

```
spyOn(myService, 'myMethod').andReturn 'myValue'
```

Should we really be using $provide for this or are there cases where spying on a service is the best approach?

In the Angular Tests they use spies for [spying on Jquery](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ccd4227cfe2e12b8a9b7f6a7a18b210fd799677c/test/ng/directive/aSpec.js#L68) which I would see as an external service.

```
spyOn(jq.prototype, 'on');
```

[$provide](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6476aed7626fa7b4adefa99c5cb4a86ed371835c/test/ng/exceptionHandlerSpec.js) seems to be used more for internal services.

```
  module(function($provide){
    $provide.provider('$exceptionHandler', $ExceptionHandlerProvider);
  });
```

There is also a Jasmine createSpy function but now I'm thinking that $provide should always take precedence over that.

Any insights or help in this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my own (limited) experience, I would say do whatever approach makes:

- The test code simpler / clearer / shorter
- Limits the assumptions about what the code your testing does internally.
- Reduces its side-affects (like running actual Ajax requests)
- Keeps the test as short as possible, in terms or run time.

Usually the `spyOn` approach works when, in order to do the above, I would like to stub a single method from a service / factory. If I need to mock an entire service / factory, then use `$provide`.

A few specific cases come to mind that require one or the other:

- If you're testing a service, then to stub other methods from that service, you'll have to use `spyOn`
- To ensure that extra dependencies aren't introduced later in the code under test, than `$provide` adds a bit more protection. Say, if you want to ensure that `ServiceA` only requires `myMethod` from `ServiceB`, then `$provide` I think would be the way to go, as if `ServiceA` calls any undefined methods from `ServiceB` during the test, errors would be raised.

  ```
  $provide.provider('ServiceB', {
      myMethod: function() {}
  });
  ```
- If you want to mock a factory that returns a function, so:

  ```
  app.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return function(option) {
      // Do something here
    }
  });
  ```

  Which is used as:

  ```
  myFactory(option);
  ```

  Then to verify that some code calls `myFactory(option)` I think there is no alternative then to use `$provide` to mock the factory.

Just by the way, they're not mutually-exclusive options. You can use `$provide` and then still  have spies involved. In the previous example, if you want to verify the factory was called with an option, you might have to:

```
var myFactorySpy = jasmine.createSpy();
$provide.provider('myFactory', myFactorySpy);
```

And then in the test at the appropriate point:

```
expect(myFactorySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(option);
```

Comment: That's helpful coming from another angle thanks. Regarding mocking a factory that returns a function - I think you can also do this using createSpy to return the function.