# Unit Testing dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am brand new to jasmine and karma.  I believe I have the environment setup properly and I am able to run very basic unit tests, but as soon as I try to instantiate a controller I am given an unknown provider error and I am unsure how to debug this.  Do I need to pass in a stateProvider dependency?  I don't see this in the angular-seed example.

Bower.json:

```
{
"name": "starter",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://starter.com",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "angular": "1.2.x",
      "angular-route": "1.2.x",
      "angular-loader": "1.2.x",
      "angular-mocks": "~1.2.15"
  }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
angular.module('home').controller('Home', function($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

    console.log($scope.pageType);

    $rootScope.pageType = 'home';

    /*
     * Takes in a state and transitions the app to that state.
     */
    $scope.goTo = function(value) {
        $state.transitionTo(value);
    }

    /*
     * Handles what happens after clicking log-in
     */
    $scope.loginClicked = function() {
        $state.transitionTo('log-in');
    }
});
```

Test file:

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */

describe('Home', function() {
    beforeEach(module('home'));

    it('should run tests', inject(function() {
        expect(null).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('should not say true equals false', function() {
        expect(false).not.toBe(true);
    });

    it('should say true equals true', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should say false does not equal true', function() {
        expect(false).not.toBe(true);
    });

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller,$rootScope) {

    /*
     * 
     * COMMENTING OUT THESE LINES = PASS
     *
     */
        var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
            ctrl = $controller('Home', {$scope:scope});
        expect(ctrl).not.toBe(null);
    }));

});
```

Error:

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state
    at /Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at /Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3705:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
    at /Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3710:45
    at getService (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
    at invoke (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:13)
    at Object.instantiate (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880:23)
    at /Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134:28
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jlett/test/unit/home-controller_tests.js:26:20)
    at Object.invoke (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869:17)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/jlett/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2132:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jlett/test/unit/home-controller_tests.js:24:54)
    at /Users/jlett/zoetis-rimadyl-mobile/test/unit/home-controller_tests.js:5:1
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are somehow not including the angular-ui-router in your karma config? Actually, I do not see that in your bower.json. Are you including ui-router??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll get this error if one of the injectables module isn't included.

For instance, you have

```
beforeEach(module('home'));
```

If your `$state` dependency is not in the `home` module, you'll need to include that module also. I'm not familiar with `$state` (I think it's angular-ui's router? Only angular.js services are supposed to start with `$`). If it's angular ui, this is how you should setup:

```
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
beforeEach(module('home'));
```

This way, angular's test runner knows what modules are required to run your tests.

Really, the inclusion of the `home` module should do this for you as long as you have the `ui.router` dependency defined as a dependency of that module.  If you have that configured correctly, you may need to look at the order of your files being included for your tests. For example, make sure the ui-router file is being included for your tests and that it is referenced before your `home` module in karma's config.

Comment: Having the same issue, I chose to include the main app module beforeEach(module('com.my.project')); which is defined as var app = angular.module('com.my.project', [
    'ngAnimate',
... , 'app.oneDomainModule', 'app.anotherDomainModule'
    ]);

Answer (score 8):

As you are including the `$state` dependency in your controller - you need to provide the `$state` in the controller unit test.

```
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new(),
    ctrl = $controller('Home', {
               $scope: $scope,
               $state: {} //Or inject the state using the injector service and then you can use some jasmine spies to mock the function calls or just to spy on 'em.
          });
    expect(ctrl).not.toBe(null);
```

Your it block with the changes....

```
it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $state) {

    /*
     * 
     * COMMENTING OUT THESE LINES = PASS
     *
     */
        var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
            ctrl = $controller('Home', {$scope:scope, $state: $state});
        expect(ctrl).not.toBe(null);
    }));
```

However at the setup of my unit tests I like to create function for controller setup as I describe in this setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830391/unit-testing-in-angularjs-mocking-services-and-promises).