# Angularjs1.6 unit testing ERROR: $scope is not defined and TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDescription' of undefine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angularjs-1.6

I testing my `angularjs 1.6.8` app with karma-jasmine. I have been constantly getting `$scope is not defined` and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDescription' of undefined`

I have tried resolving them. did some googling. but no luck. Not sure, what I am doing wrong.

Below are the related codes.

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$translateProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$translateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        component: 'dashboardComponent'
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        component: 'contactComponent'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        component: 'aboutComponent'
      })
      .state('sassSite', {
        url: '/sassSite',
        templateUrl: 'sassSite.html'
      })

      $translateProvider.preferredLanguage(navigator.language);
      $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en','fr','hi'],{
        'en-*':'en',
        'fr-*':'fr',
        'hi-*':'hi'
      });
      $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
          prefix:'i18n/',
          suffix:'.json'
      });
      $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','$translate',function($scope, $translate){
  $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang){
    $translate.use(lang);
  }
}]);

app.service('contactService',function(){
});
```

`karma.conf.js`

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Feb 11 2018 13:41:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

      'src/scripts/angular.js',
      'src/scripts/angular-mocks.js',      

      'src/scripts/angular-route.js',
      'src/scripts/angular-ui-router.js',

      'src/scripts/app.js',

      'src/components/contact/contact.component.js',
      'src/components/contact/contact.service.js',
      'src/unitest.spec.js',
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

`unit.spec.js`

```
describe('Controller', function() {
    // beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');
        angular.module('ui.router',[]);


        angular.module('pascalprecht.translate',[]);



      });

    describe('contactController',function(){
        var contactController;
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
            contactController = $controller('contactController');
        }));
        it('should submit user details', function(){
            contactController.setDescription('nauman');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
            contactController.setDescription('ntanwir10@gmail.com');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
            contactController.setDescription('too hot bruh!');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

so I modified my `unit.spec.js`

```
describe('Controller', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'stateProvider','pascalprecht.translate' ] );
      });

    describe('contactController',function(){
        var contactController;
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
            contactController = $controller('contactController',{$scope: $scope});
        }));
        it('should submit user details', function(){
            contactController.setDescription('nauman');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
            contactController.setDescription('ntanwir10@gmail.com');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
            contactController.setDescription('too hot bruh!');
            expect(contactController.description).toBe(string);
        });
    });
});
```

and now I getting the below errors(check screenshot):

[image: updated screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Testing dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253941/unit-testing-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Below is the solution.

`unit.spec.js`

```
describe('Controller', function() {
    describe('contactController',function(){
         it('should submit user details', function(){

           module('myApp');
           var scope={};
           var ctrl;
        });

        inject(function($controller){
            ctrl  = $controller('contactController', {$scope:scope});

            ctrl.setDescription('nauman');
            expect(ctrl.description).toBe(string);
            ctrl.setDescription('ntanwir10@gmail.com');
            expect(ctrl.description).toBe(string);
            ctrl.setDescription('too hot bruh!');
            expect(ctrl.description).toBe(string);
        });
    });
});
```