# Jasmine Testing for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Unable to test data returned by Promise variable.In my code there is one factory function drawgraph() in which json data is retrieved by $http service.In controller I am using promise for checking Success Callback and retrieval of data.So I cant get data outside promise.then() function.How I can write jasmine test cases for checking that data values.

Comment: Take a look at using [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) in your tests ... you can setup a canned response with it. It can get tedious at times. You might also show some code, so someone can give you a more concrete example/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a stackoverflow question and answer to help with this kinda thing.

Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830391/unit-testing-in-angularjs-mocking-services-and-promises)

If this doesnt help you to get started then post some code!

This is an example of unit test - a small art of a unit test - that uses $httpBackend

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, Products, PATH) {

        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.when('JSONP', PATH.url + 'products?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').respond(PRODUCTS);

}));
```