# Angular / jasmine / promise / mocking testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise

I'm a little screwed up with angular / jasmine / promise / mocking testing.

I have a piece of code:

```
factory.login = function(user, pwd) {
    AuthenticationResource.login( {}, {"username" : user, "password" : pwd},
        factory.onLoginSuccess,
        factory.onLoginFailure
    );
};
```

Then I'm trying to write a test:

```
  it('login', function() {

        // give
        // 1. make 'authenticationResource.login' return a promise that will be successfully resolved
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;

        authenticationResource.login = function() {
            //deferred.resolve(loginResponse);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        // 2. call 'factory.login' and make sure that 'onLoginSuccess' function was invoked as expected

        // then
        //expect(..
    });
```

**Could you pointing me to right direction. Seems that all looks a bit different from what I've got to with Java/Mockito.**?

Then `AuthenticationResource` itself is here:

```
angular.module('main.resources').factory('AuthenticationResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/rest/authenticate/:path',
        {path: "@path"}, //parameters default
        {
            login:  { method: "POST", params: { path: "login" } },
            logout: { method: "POST", params: { path: "logout" } }
        });
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing in AngularJS - Mocking Services and Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830391/unit-testing-in-angularjs-mocking-services-and-promises)

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830391/unit-testing-in-angularjs-mocking-services-and-promises)

Mocking promises is difficult until u see the light!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but in case anyone else stumbles across it - I wrote [jasmine-promise-matchers](http://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) to help with this issue.

With it, you can test promises simply, like:

```
expect(promise).toBeRejected();
expect(promise).toBeRejectedWith('expected error message');
expect(promise).toBeResolved();
expect(promise).toBeResolvedWith('expected result data');
```

Comment: I had planned to use it.

Comment: Nice to hear. :) Let me know if it's lacking any features you'd like.